# Change JQuery ui select option with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

Here is a working version of my code so far. What I am trying to achieve is to change the selection of the JQuery dropdown select combobox using a separate button called "next".

The result I would like is: every time I press the "next" button the JQuery dropdown should change automatically to the next selection.

So If I have selected Q2 from the dropdown combobox, and then I press the "next" button I would like the dropdown menu to automatically change and select Q3 and alert me the  ui.item.value.

I hope this is making sense. This functionality is useful because if you have many questions it is easier to press a button and move on the next selection.

I have written a function called "next" but I don't know what to put in there. I have tried various things but nothing seems to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Page</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

                            <!--JQuery ref-->        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>


            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>



            <style>
                              /*JQuery styleing*/

                .ui-widget {
                       font-size: 18px;
                       font-family:  sans-serif; /*styling for the text inside the dropdown box*/

                    }


                .custom-combobox {
                    position: absolute;
                    display: inline-block;
                 /*top: 20px;*/ /*Position of the control box*/          
                  /*  left:224px; controld combobox left to right*/
                }

                .custom-combobox-toggle {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0px; /* controls the height of the arrow box*/
                    bottom: 0;
                    margin-left: -1px;
                    padding: 0;
                    /* support: IE7 */
                    *height: 1.7em;
                    *top: 0.1em;

                }
                /*Controls the width of the inputbox*/
                .custom-combobox-input {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0.3em;
                    width: 700px;
                    /*color: red;*/
                }

                .ui-autocomplete {    
                    max-height: 250px; /*Max height of scrollbar*/
                    max-width:  800px; /*Max width of items dropdown box */
                    overflow-y: auto;   /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
                    overflow-x: hidden; /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
                    z-index:1000 !important;
                }
            </style>    

            <script>
                (function( $ ) {$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
              _create: function() {this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                      .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
                      .insertAfter( this.element );
                      this.element.hide();
                      this._createAutocomplete();
                      this._createShowAllButton();}//creates the dropdownbutton
                  ,

              _createAutocomplete: function() {
                  var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
              value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "Please select a question"; //adds default title in dropdownbox




                this.input = $( "<input>" )
                .appendTo( this.wrapper )
                .val( value )
                .attr( "title", "" )
                .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
                .autocomplete({
                delay: 0,
                minLength: 0,
                source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
                })
                .tooltip({
                tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"});

                this._on( this.input, {
                autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.item.option.selected = true;
                this._trigger( "select", event, {
                item: ui.item.option});


                }
                ,


                autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
                });
                },

                _createShowAllButton: function() {
                var input = this.input,
                wasOpen = false;
                $( "<a>" )
                .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                .attr( "title", "Show more" )
                .attr("id","dd") //I have added this attribute of code to allow me to change the menu button colour see css above
                .tooltip()
                .appendTo( this.wrapper )
                .button({
                icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s" //You can change the icon from the original to anything else eg: ui-icon-triangle-1-s
                },
                text: false
                })
                .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
                .mousedown(function() {
                wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
                })
                .click(function() {
                input.focus();
                // Close if already visible
                if ( wasOpen ) {
                return;
                }
                // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                });
                },
                _source: function( request, response ) {
                var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                var text = $( this ).text();
                if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                return {
                label: text,
                value: text,
                option: this
                };
                }) );
                },
                _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
                // Selected an item, nothing to do
                if ( ui.item ) {
                return;
                }
                // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
                var value = this.input.val(),
                valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
                valid = false;
                this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
                this.selected = valid = true;
                return false;
                }
                });
                // Found a match, nothing to do
                if ( valid ) {
                return;
                }
                // Remove invalid value
                this.input
                .val( "" )
                .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
                .tooltip( "open" );
                this.element.val( "" );
                this._delay(function() {
                this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
                }, 2500 );
                this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
                },
                _destroy: function() {
                this.wrapper.remove();
                this.element.show();
                }
                });
                })( jQuery );

            </script>            

        </head>

<body>

    <button id="next" onclick="next()">next</button>


    <select id="dropdown">                          
    <option value="" selected ="selected" disabled="disabled">Select question </option>
    <option  value = "Q1">Q1 </option>
    <option  value = "Q2">Q2 </option>
    <option  value = "Q3">Q3 </option>
    <option  value = "Q4">Q4 </option>
    <option  value = "Q5">Q5 </option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#dropdown").combobox({ 
                        select: function (event, ui) { 
                                alert(ui.item.value);//gives me the value of the dropdownbox eveytime I select a question             
                        }                
                }
        );


        function next(){

        //I would like to fire a function that changes the dropdown box selection to the next selection when I click a button.
        //I can do this with a simple select statement but does not work when I am using a JQuery ui.
        //there is  a fiddle which  I found doing something similar but I can't get it to work with the ui. http://jsfiddle.net/gN3ke/  

        }    

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "JQuery ui select"..? Can you link to the plugin you're using..?

Comment: this is the plugin I am using thanks.http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox   looks at the source code . not sure why someone has downed my question

Comment: @probably because you haven't mentioned what you're using. You're actually using a customized version of the *autocomplete* widget, unless you explicitly mention it, nobody will understand what you're talking about...

Comment: BTW, By default the dropdown will close once you click anywhere including a button, so...? Please update the question mentioning the source of code, expected result etc.

Comment: Thanks TJ I have updated the question with the entire code which can be pasted into an html page so that you can see what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tokool/e339zu9t/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok After much searching and a lot of trial and error I found my own solution! Having a next button is very useful especially when you have many questions in your dropdown combobox ui. It's probably not the most efficient solution but a good enough work around!

Here is the code I needed for the next function to work:

```
 function next()
 {

   $('#dropdown').combobox("destroy");//first destroy the current JQuery combobox

   $("#dropdown option:selected").removeAttr("selected"); //deselect the currently selected option

    document.getElementById("dropdown").selectedIndex = 3; //now that the JQuery combobox is destroyed and currently selected attribute is deselected, add a new attribute, in the underlying select statement. I have put this as a static value 'Q3' just as an example but this process can also be fully automated so that every time next is pressed it rolls over to the next question.

    $('#dropdown').combobox(); // Now recreate the nice JQuery combobox and call it.

//Finally, call the JQuery combobox select event, ui so that the user can select questions from the dropdown box as simply calling the combobox does not reactivate the ui select function.  
    $("#dropdown").combobox({ 
        select: function (event, ui) { 

          alert(ui.item.value);  //this will alert when a question is selected from the dropdown box again.

             }
           }      

     );


      alert(document.getElementById("dropdown").value); //this alerts to next button.
 }
```